# How to differentiate the trace of a matrix times its diagonal

Tags: matrices, derivatives, solution-verification, matrix-calculus

Let $\mathbf{\Theta}\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ be a matrix and denote $\mbox{diag}(\mathbf{\Theta})\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ the matrix that has the same diagonal as $\mathbf{\Theta}$ and every off-diagonal element zero. I am trying to calculate

$$\frac{\partial \|\mathbf{X}\,[\mathbf{I}-\,(\mathbf{\Theta}-\mbox{diag}(\mathbf{\Theta}))]\,\|_{F}^{2} }{\partial \mathbf{\Theta}}$$

where $\|\cdot\|_{F}$ denotes the Frobenius norm, $\mathbf{I}$ the identity matrix and $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$.

The frobenius norm is equal to
\begin{align*}
&tr(\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X})+tr(\mathbf{\Theta}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\Theta})+tr(diag(\mathbf{\Theta})\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X}diag(\mathbf{\Theta})\\
&-2tr(\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\Theta})+2tr(\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X}diag(\mathbf{\Theta}))-2tr(diag(\mathbf{\Theta})\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\Theta})
\end{align*}

I have also worked out the derivatives to be
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial tr(\mathbf{\Theta}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\Theta})}{\partial\mathbf{\Theta}}=2\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\Theta}, \frac{\partial tr(diag(\mathbf{\Theta})\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X}diag(\mathbf{\Theta})}{\partial\mathbf{\Theta}}=2diag(\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X})diag(\mathbf{\Theta})\\
&\frac{\partial tr(\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\Theta})}{\partial\mathbf{\Theta}}=\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X},\frac{\partial tr(\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X}diag(\mathbf{\Theta}))}{\partial \mathbf{\Theta}}=diag(\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X}),\\
&\frac{\partial tr(diag(\mathbf{\Theta})\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\Theta})}{\partial\mathbf{\Theta}}=(\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X})diag(\mathbf{\Theta})+diag(\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\Theta}).
\end{align*}

But when I replace I get
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial ||\mathbf{X}\,[\mathbf{I}-\,(\mathbf{\Theta}-diag(\mathbf{\Theta}))]\,||_{F}^{2} }{\partial \mathbf{\Theta}}=2\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\Theta}-2diag(\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\Theta})+2diag(\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X})-2\mathbf{X}^{\intercal}\mathbf{X},
\end{align*}
which I think is wrong because the right hand side includes components from the diagonal of $\mathbf{\Theta}$ while the left hand side does not.

As I am not very good with matrix calculus, I would appreciate any intuition. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just remove the identity matrix?

Comment: This seems to be $\lVert\cdot\rVert_F^2$ composed with a linear mapping. Can't you just use the chain rule?

Comment: I am sorry it should have been $\frac{||\mathbf{X}\,[\mathbf{I}-(\mathbf{\Theta}-diag(\mathbf{\Theta}))]\,||_{F}^{2}}{\partial \mathbf{\Theta}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the identity matrix $I$ and the all-ones matrix $J$ to define the *off-diagonal* matrix
$$F = J-I$$
For typing convenience, define the matrices
$$\eqalign{
A &= \Theta \\B &= X(F\odot A)-X \\
}$$
and use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$M:N = {\rm Tr}(M^TN) = {\rm Tr}(MN^T)$$
Write the cost function using the new notation and calculate its gradient
$$\eqalign{
\psi &= B:B \\
d\psi &= 2B:dB \\
 &= 2B:X(F\odot dA) \\
 &= 2\Big((X^TB)\odot F\Big):dA \\
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial A}
 &= 2(X^TB)\odot F \\
}$$

---

Some of the steps above utilized the cyclic property 
of the Frobenius product, e.g.
$$A:BC = B^TA:C = AC^T:B = etc$$
its relationship to the Frobenius norm
$$\|B\|^2_F = B:B$$
and the fact that it commutes with the Hadamard product
$$A:(B\odot C) = (A\odot B):C$$

Comment: Very good explanation. Thank you!